# Парсинг и отправка данных через telegram бота

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть самописный бот на питоне, суть которого мониторить предметы, и если критерии совпали, то покупать предмет. Я хотел добавить к нему бота, чтобы после покупки он отправлял сообщение с данными купленного предмета. Хотел написать бота на `aiogram`, но поискав в интернете, так и не нашел способа, как сделать отправку данных прайм-тайм без отправки команды пользователем. Я бы хотел, чтобы бот сам отправлял сообщения, без участия пользователя. Не могли бы вы скинуть ссылки на похожие статьи, или каким способом можно через `aiogram` реализовать подобный кейс. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле, решение вашей проблемы лежит на поверхности. Если предположить, что `bot` — объект типа `Bot`, то тогда всё решается с помощью следующей функции, которая будет срабатывать после покупки предмета:

```py
async def send_data_about_buying(some_data):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, some_data)
```

Здесь `chat_id` — ID чата с вашим ботом, который можно получить выводом `event.message.chat.id` при срабатывании `message_handler`, а `some_data` — какая-то информация о товаре, которую вы хотите отправить. Учтите, что для отправки сообщения боту требуется доступ к чату с вами, т.е. у вас уже должен быть с ним диалог.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию

Comment: @MKS, отметьте вопрос как принятый, если он помог решить вашу проблему.